# Is there a similar expression to "level the score" in American English?

Tags: meaning, american-english, british-english

I'm non-native English speaker and I found the expression "level the score" in dictionary was denoted as "British English". So I want to know if there is a counterpart in the US English.

Comment: [Handicapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handicapping).

Comment: Wouldn't handicapping be more like levelling the playing field? Or is this a regional thing? In Australian English to level the score is normally taken pretty literally, ie. one player or team has scored and the scores are now level.

Comment: In Britain it can vary according to sport. In football, for example, whilst *level the score* is perfectly understood and sometimes used, the far more common expression is that *United equalised against Arsenal in the 54th minute*. An *equaliser* is a goal which *levels the score*. However *equalise* is less appropriate in sports like rugby and cricket. In either *levelled the score* would seem appropriate in unusual situations where the scores are exactly equal.

Answer (score 6):

In American English we use the term "even the score."  There are many many examples of this revealed with a quick google search.

At no point in watching sports in the US would announcers or fans use the term level for two teams with the same score. More commonly, the teams are tied at 30, even at 30, or the score is 30 all.

Answer (score 2):

"get even" is one phrase that comes to my mind.

However, this phrase has a negative feel about it since Cambridge Dictionary gives the meaning of this as "to punish someone who has done something bad to you by doing something equally bad to that person"

However, having said that, in a sport, if an opponent scores against you, it is "bad" against you in the context of sport. Right ?